# Issue populating data in jquery datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

This is my **/Books/userHome** view:

```
@model CSBSTest.Models.tbl_Book
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "UserHome";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Profile.cshtml";
}

<h2>Books for sale by CUST Students</h2>


<br />
<br />
<table id="books" class="table table-bordered table-hover">

    <thead>

        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Book Name</th>
            <th>Author</th>
            <th>Version</th>

        </tr>

    </thead>

    <tbody></tbody>
</table>

@section scripts
{
    <script>
    $(document).ready( function () {
        var dataTable = $("#books").DataTable({
            ajax: {

            url: "/Book/GetBooks",

            dataSrc: ""


        },
        columns: [
            {
                data:"Id"
            },
            {

                data: "Name"
            },

            {

                data: "Author"

            },

            {
                data: "Version"
            }

        ]


    });
});
</script>
}
```

I am calling /Books/GetBooks as below:

```
public ActionResult UserHome()
    {
        return View();
    }


    public ActionResult GetBooks()
    {
        var list = _context.tbl_Book.ToList();
        return Json(list, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

The GetBooks returns json result which is called from UserHome scripts section as shown above, I want to populate the list returned by /Books/GetBooks  into jquery datatable but its gives the following exception:
[image: Click to view error/exception].
any help will be highly appreciated thanks in advance.

Comment: are you using `google chrome` as browser? try to `ctrl+shift+i` and go to network tab. refresh page first.  click `XHR` to see preview/response of your table

Comment: Are you using a jquery plugin for the datatable? like this https://datatables.net/

Comment: yes sir i am using Jquery datatable plugin

Comment: Are you ajax returning a data object? if it is, try removing (dataSrc: "") from the config. if not, you need to tell it to bind on the prop that contains your data. think this can be the error

Comment: Also. do what drenyl said, be sure the data you want to get from ajax, is returning the way you think.

Comment: Request URL: http://localhost:60953/Book/GetBooks?_=1525850183396
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 500 Internal Server Error
Remote Address: [::1]:60953
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade @Drenyl thisis what network tab shows

Comment: @MuhammadAli have you tried running it i debug? ever getting in the api?

Comment: @MuhammadAli 500 internal server error means basically there something wrong in your server side. Commonly i getting this kind of error in my query. Please include your code on how you execute your query

Comment: @Drenyl i have added code thats getting list and returning as json list above

Comment: @MuhammadAli What happens if you directly invoke /Book/GetBooks ? Do you get a stack trace?

Comment: I can help your further if I can see the structure of `json` you're returning or the query that you have

Comment: It is internal server error, you need to debug GetBooks, better add try catch and check the exception thrown, and add that exception details to your question.

Comment: When i directly execute GetBooks method it gives exception as follow: "A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.tbl_Book_15AA3FF8E52B02868CFB681CFE7DA0362529096BECCBE5A3BAE6FE2E2C2557ED'."

Answer (score 0):

```
var list = _context.tbl_Book.ToList();
```

Here "list" is database table object and  you should not return it directly.
Use user defined model and than return it

```
public class customModel{
//properties

}

var list = _context.tbl_Book.ToList();

List<custommodel> test = list.select(a=>new custommodel{
//assingn properties
});
 return Json(test , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```